# Comparing between nucleophilic and basic strength of acetylene ion

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides, nucleophilic-substitution, elimination

**Question**
[image]

In this question I understand that 2 reactions- Substitution and elimination- will occur. But which will be major?

Comment: I think you can immediately eliminate answer a and d. The conjuated alkene wil be preferentially formed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is (b); majority elimination by an E2 mechanism.

Quoting from [chem.libretext.org:](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Map%3A_Organic_Chemistry_(McMurry)/09%3A_Alkynes_-_An_Introduction_to_Organic_Synthesis/9.08%3A_Alkylation_of_Acetylide_Anions)

> Acetylide anions are strong bases and strong
>   nucleophiles[...] Secondary, tertiary or even bulky primary substrates
>   will give elimination by the E2 mechanism.

Comment: But how do u compare between its basicity and nycleophilicity ?

Comment: That is really rather difficult to compare because solvent effects, counter-ion and electrophile differences make very reaction different. Chemistry is complex!